# GI - Conditional Result Column

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to do a conditional statement that displays the inventory items that contain w3 in the ID. I then need to use the same GI and create another column that displays the inventory item that contains FG in the INV ID.

I have tried this expression without any success:

```
=IIf( 'w3' In [left(inventoryCD,2)], inventoryCD, null )
=IIf( 'FG' In [left(inventoryCD,2)], inventoryCD, null )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `InStr` instead of `In` operator. Here is example above:

```
=IIf(InStr(Left(InventoryCD,2),'w3')>0, InventoryCD, null )
=IIf(InStr(Left(InventoryCD,2),'FG')>0, InventoryCD, null )
```